# Minio Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: python, kubernetes, minio

I have a k8s cluster with 3 nodes and I am trying to deploy MinIO.

Below is the StatefulSet, Services and Ingresses:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: ches
  name: ches
spec:
  serviceName: ches
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ches
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ches
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ches-serviceaccount
      nodeSelector:
        ches-worker: "true"
      volumes:
      - name: data
        hostPath:
          path: /data/test
      containers:
      - name: ches
        image: repo.cha-project.eu/h/edgestorage/minio/minio:test
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        securityContext:
            privileged: true
        args:
        - server
        - --console-address
        - :9011
        - /data
        env:
        - name: MINIO_SERVER_URL
          value: https://mygui.name.name-project.eu
        - name: MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL
          value: https://mygui.name.name-project.eu/login
        - name: CONSOLE_SECURE_TLS_REDIRECT
          value: "off"
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: ches-keys
              key: access-key
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: ches-keys
              key: secret-key
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          #hostPort: 9011
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: edge-storage-token
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mygui
  namespace: ches
  labels:
    app: ches
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: ches
  ports:
  - port: 9012
    targetPort: 9011
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapi
  namespace: ches
  labels:
    app: ches
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: ches
  ports:
  - port: 9011
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: ches-gui-ingress
    namespace: ches
    annotations:
      nginx.org/redirect-to-https: "true"
      nginx.org.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: mygui.name.name-project.eu
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: mygui
            port:
              number: 9012
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: ches-api-ingress
    namespace: ches
    annotations:
      nginx.org/redirect-to-https: "true"
      nginx.org.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myapi.name.name-project.eu
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myapi
            port:
              number: 9011
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

I have setup everything else from Namespaces to ServiceAccounts etc.

When I try to accees the API with:

```
import logging
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import S3Error
from multiprocessing import Process

# execute from IDE terminal
minio = Minio(
    'myapi.name.name-project.eu',
    access_key='mykey',
    secret_key='mysecret',
    secure=False,
)

def list_all_buckets():
    #files_num = 0
    bucket_list = minio.list_buckets()
    for bucket in bucket_list:
        objects = minio.list_objects(bucket.name, recursive=True)
        print ("bucket name:", bucket.name)
        # for obj in objects:
        #     files_num += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        list_all_buckets()
    except S3Error as exc:
        print("error occurred.", exc)
        logging.critical("Object storage not reachable")
```

It works and the following output is produced (I have these buckets):

> bucket name: charitybucket

> bucket name: weweffwe

However, when I try to access the console I got:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

If I remove:

```
- name: MINIO_SERVER_URL
  value: https://mygui.name.name-project.eu
- name: MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL
  value: https://mygui.name.name-project.eu/login
- name: CONSOLE_SECURE_TLS_REDIRECT
  value: "off"
```

I have access to the console, however I have the following error (browser console):

> objectBrowserWSMiddleware.ts:180 Error in websocket connection.
> Attempting reconnection...

and in the Newteork tab:

[image]

[image]

Is anyone knows what am I doing wrong?